# Azure Search how to ignore empty blob files (without content)?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

In my blob storage documents exists that are empty. Final azure search's document looks like this:

```
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 19.593246,
        "@search.highlights": {
            "original_title": [
                "<em>Divine</em> <em>Secrets</em> of the Ya-Ya Sisterhood"
            ],
            "title": [
                "<em>Divine</em> <em>Secrets</em> of the Ya-Ya Sisterhood"
            ]
        },
        "original_title": "Divine Secrets of the Ya-Ya Sisterhood",
        "title": "Divine Secrets of the Ya-Ya Sisterhood"
        "content": "" // this is empty
    }
]
```

And as you can see, `content` can be empty because there is nothing in "Divine Secrets of the Ya-Ya Sisterhood" blob file.

My question is how to `ignore` empty blob files in `data source` or during `indexing` process and is it posible to throw `indexing` error (or any) when empty file appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#determine-which-blobs-to-index), I would say it is not possible to either exclude zero-sized blobs from indexing or throw an error during indexing for such blobs.

One possible solution would be to set a metadata property (`AzureSearch_Skip`) with value as `true` when uploading blobs that do not have any content (for existing blobs, you would need to manually update the metadata). Presence of this metadata property would instruct Azure Search to ignore such blobs from indexing.

Comment: That's clear for me, thanks! I can still throw error from webskill if i am correct? For example, i set some metadata like `isEmpty` in blob file -> if true, throw error from webskill